# Type class API in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

This is a pattern I am considering to use in Scala to define a contract without limiting the type but still having a fluent API without all the verbose implicity[..].

The idea is to build a implicit class on top of a type class like so:

```
implicit class NumberLikeApi[N : NumberLike](n: N)
  def add(n2: N): N = implicitely[NumberLike[N]].add(n, n2)
}
```

Now with the right implicits in scope you can do:

```
val sum = n1.add(n2)
```

Instead of:

```
val sum = implicitly[NumberLike[N]].add(n1, n2)
```

My question: Is it somehow possible to automate / generate the implicit class part? It is basically a duplication of the type class.

I failed to find something in the language & standard library. Is there perhaps a macro in a library somewhere that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of [`simulacrum`](https://github.com/mpilquist/simulacrum) should be exactly this.

From its README, you can write

```
import simulacrum._

@typeclass trait Semigroup[A] {
  @op("|+|") def append(x: A, y: A): A
}
```

and then use it like

```
// instance for Semigroup[Int] 
implicit val semigroupInt: Semigroup[Int] = new Semigroup[Int] {
  def append(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
}

import Semigroup.ops._

1 |+| 2 // 3
```

Comment: Awesome!, did not know about this one. Somehow failed to find it in my search attempts. Many thanks, this makes the pattern somewhat usable.